# How can I change the color of multiple specific words in a string?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a function that can read through large a string of text, automatically detect keywords, and then change the color of these individual words. For example, in the sentence, "he walked to the store and then he walked to his house," I want the function to individually detect the word "he" and change the text color to green, while also detecting the word "walked" to change the text color to red without altering the rest of the sentence. This would be on a much greater scale with more keywords and colors.

I've gotten to the point where I can get my program to detect certain words in a string of text written in a  or , but when I attempt to change the color of the words through there, it changes the color of all of the words in the string (by altering the CSS), which isn't what I want. I also got it to change the individual word within a , but it changed the words within other  sections as well.

I'm also having difficulty getting it to change the different keywords, for example when it uses the color green for "walked" when it should actually be red. I don't want to manually use  around every single word, so I would like to find a way to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let see why may have problem with your approach:**

- Your pattern may not match whole word that why it changed the words within other sections as well.
- you does not have color assign approach

**How we can fix it :**

- we can have a method getWordAndColor for set color to word
- We can have another method to change the sentence word to specified color

```js
const getWordAndColor = () => {
        let wordAndColor = {};
        wordAndColor['he'] = 'green';
        wordAndColor['walked'] = 'red';
        wordAndColor['store'] = '#4682B4';
        return wordAndColor;
    }
    const setColorToWord = (wordAndColor, sentence) => {
        for (let key in wordAndColor) {

            if (wordAndColor.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                let value = wordAndColor[key];
                let dynamicPattern = key;
                let pattern = new RegExp("\\b" + dynamicPattern + "\\b", 'gi');
                let replacement = '<span style="color: '+value+';">'+key+'</span>';
                sentence = sentence.replace(pattern, replacement);
            }
        }

        return sentence;
    }

    let sentence = "he walked to the store and then he walked to his house,";
    let wordAndColor = getWordAndColor();
    document.getElementById('wordAndColorText').innerHTML = setColorToWord(wordAndColor, sentence);
```

```html
<div id="wordAndColorText"></div>
```

Comment: Holy cow, thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate you so much!!!

Comment: @cerdessius, thank you, happy to see it working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example.

this function to individually detect the word "he" and change the text color to green, while also detecting the word "walked" to change the text color to red without altering the rest of the sentence.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Coloring Words</title>
  
  <!-- Include jQuery from a CDN (Content Delivery Network) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="coloredText">he walked to the store and then he walked to his house</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var coloredText = $("#coloredText").text();
  var keywordClasses = {
    "he": "green",
    "walked": "red",
   
  };
  var words = coloredText.split(/\s+/);

 
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i].toLowerCase(); // Convert to lowercase for case-insensitivity
    var cssClass = keywordClasses[word];
    if (cssClass) {
      words[i] = "<span class='" + cssClass + "'>" + words[i] + "</span>";
    }
  }

 
  $("#coloredText").html(words.join(' '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For pure javascript, you can do this

```js
// Original string
const original = 'he walked to the store and then he walked to his house,'
// Set original string
document.querySelector("#original").innerText = original

// On form submit
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", onSubmit)
// On form submit handler
function onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // Styled output
  let output = original
  
  // Get text to be converted to green
  const greenText = document.querySelector("#toGreen").value
  // Get text to be converted to yellow
  const yellowText = document.querySelector("#toYellow").value

  // Change all `greenText` to green and return
  output = changeColor(output, greenText, 'green')
  // Change all `yellowText` to yellow and return
  output = changeColor(output, yellowText, 'yellow')

  // Print styled string to screen
  document.querySelector("#styled").innerHTML = output
}

function changeColor(string, text, color) {
  return string.replace(text, `<span style="color: ${color}">${text}</span>`)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">To green:</label>
  <input type="text" id="toGreen"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">To yellow:</label>
  <input type="text" id="toYellow"><br><br>  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<h3>Original</h6>
<div id="original"> he walked to the store and then he walked to his house,</div>
<h3>After</h6>
<div id="styled"> he walked to the store and then he walked to his house,</div>
```

In the snippet, input word that need to be changed to 'green' and 'yellow'. Then press `Submit`

To actual change a word color inside a string, you need to wrap it inside a `<span/>`. Then change that `<span/>` CSS only

`changeColor` method will wrap specific word inside `<span/> and change it color, then return the styled string. Then you can put this styled string in` element.innerHTML`